# Passing data around ViewControllers in MVVM and RxSwift

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm

I have data that comes from different view controllers (with a separate viewmodel for each one) and to be shown in a main view controller. How do you implement the passing of data between one view controller to the main view controller using RxSwift and MVVM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I caveat my answer in that I can't speak for RxSwift.  I recommend you have the two ViewModels converse with a model or other controller of your app that coordinates the data between them.  Remember, you want to be able to write tests for each of your ViewController classes independently from any other ViewController (at least from a data point of view - view stack is another matter). And your ViewController tests should let you swap in a mock ViewModel.  And you want to be able to test each ViewModel independently of any ViewController or any other ViewModel as well.

So your best bet is to keep your VCs simply contractually talking with their ViewModel.  And each ViewModel can converse also with outside models and controllers & services - preferrably in a way that allows for dependency injection so you can mock those controllers & services when testing your ViewModel.

By keeping your testing needs always in mind when architecting, you'll quickly deduce what's right.

Answer (score 2):

Inject a Navigator object into your ViewControllers. This object should provide functions for navigating to each of your ViewControllers given a the needed data parameters. Eg:

```
  func showSceneX(param1: String, param2: Int, sender: UIViewController) {
     let vm = SomeViewModel(param1: param1, param2: param2)
     let vc = SomeViewController.createWith(navigator: self, viewModel: vm)
     // Show the desired view controller. from the previous one
     sender.present(target, animated: true, completion: nil)
  }
```

By isolating this logic into a dedicated object you get more flexibility out of your view controllers and you can set your mocks as desired for tests that encompass multiple ViewControllers.